# Convert Jruby HashMap to Java HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, jruby

I need to pass a hashmap from a jruby function into a Java function.  I have tried it this way with no luck.

```
def rubyfunction
    clazz = com.package.clazz
    params = java.util.HashMap.new({:ID => 1})       
    clazz.javafunction(params)
end


public class clazz{
    public void javafunction(HashMap<String, Object> params){
        params.get("ID") //Gives back null
    }
}
```

Is there a proper way to convert a jruby hashmap into a java hashmap?

Comment: What do you mean "no luck"?  Is there an error?

Comment: When trying to grab the value with the key of "ID" it gives back null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking for a few hours I came across this link https://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/CallingJavaFromJRuby

From that I modified the code, which now works as intended

```
def rubyfunction
    clazz = com.package.clazz
    params = java.util.HashMap.new()
    value = 1.to_java Java::int
    params.put("ID", value)
    clazz.javafunction(params)
end
```